# Startup orientation is wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

I'm new to StackOverflow, and also new to objective-c.

I have tried looking for a couple weeks now to find something that gives me a hint of what to do, but I can't seem to get through this one without asking a question. It feels like it should be simple, but...

I'm having a problem with the rotation of a "rootView" controller. It should show up in landscape (which it did, before I decided to use a navigation controller). The simulator shows up in the correct orientation, but it has loaded the view rotated 90 degress left, so that the text reads from bottom to top, sideways, so you have to cock your head left. The leftmost portion of the view is visible, but the remainder of the view runs off the top of the screen. It's a large program (I'm finding that, in general, with objective-c, but enjoying it nonetheless...), but here's the gist of what I think are the important code areas:

In the appDelegate, I create a window, my rootViewcontroller, and the navcontroller:

```
// .h file:
UIWindow *window;
wordHelper3ViewController *viewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then in the implementation:

```
//.m file
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Hide status bar
    application.statusBarHidden = YES;
        // --- Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Then I release all of these in the dealloc.

In my root view, I'm doing this:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I implemented the following, to see what was happening, and I'm getting the log message on startup immediately:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"didRotate...");
    }
}
```

Other than this, I don't think I'm doing anything in my code that should affect the view(s). So now, on to InterfaceBuilder:

In the attributes inspector for both the rootView and the navigation controller, the orientation is set to landscape. For the rootView, under referencing outlets, the “view” is set to file's owner. I also have an action attached to the view (touchUpInside) – I changed its class to UIButton, because I wanted to resignFirstResponder when the user clicks anywhere in the background.

For the navigationController, under Referencing outlets, it shows a connection from the navigationController to my appDelegate.

In the main window xib, the nav contoller shows up in the list, and the view controller shows up as a subview of it.

The viewcontroller also shows up on its own, in the main window's list of objects.

The only thing that stands out to me, is that when I double click the window object, IT comes up visually in portrait mode.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you mind posting a screenshot, your description is a little unclear.

Comment: The screenshot is posted on my Google docs page - here's the link:  

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kZMPTsqVT6yAdxCa1HPXu0jhZnDa4QOsJ3p9_wqYs5Q/edit?hl=en&authkey=CJf58PEG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are adding your navigation controller as a subview to the window and orientation notifications are only sent to the first subview in "window".

Try this instead.

```
//.m file
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Hide status bar
    application.statusBarHidden = YES;
        // --- Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [viewController.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Its annoying, but I've resolved orientation problems by only every having one subview in "window" and then controlling everything through that one subview (in this case viewController)

Answer (score 13):

If you want the startup orientation to be different from the initial Portrait mode, you need to edit your `info.plist` file. Add an entry for "intial interface orientation" and set the value that you want.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

If you want to rotate a UINavigationController, it will take a bit more work. See [this similar question for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843460/rotating-view-controllers-within-a-hierarchy-of-tab-bar-controller-navigation/4843641#4843641) more information.

Comment: I did that already. My initial interface orientation is set to Landscape (home right button)

Comment: It is the UINavigationController that needs to be rotated, I think. I'll have a look at the related question, see if that helps. Thank you for your attention, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hi - I read it, and it didn't solve the problem. The actual window object in INterface Builder, when double-clicked, appears in portrait orientation, and when I try to change the dimensions in the size inspector, they're are greyed out, preventing me from changing their values. My gut is telling me i need to change the width and height of the window object. Can anyone tell me how I might accomplish this - perhaps programmatically?

Comment: You can resize the view in IB, but you need to hide the view's simulated elements first. (simulated status bar and possibly navigation bar.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the view and the window are different, right? All my views are showing up correctly in design - it's the window that's showing up in IB in portrait orientation. There doesn't seem to be any simulated elements in the window. I have them all turned off. Problem - as soon as I set the NavController's delegate to my app delegate, the orientation gets messed up.

Comment: The view and the window are different. you can try setting the delegate programatically. Perhaps that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but shouldn't this

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

really be this

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

?

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I started with, and it did the same thing. Then I changed it, because I was having difficulty understanding what that method actually does. I left it this way because it kind of made more sense to me. But yes, that's what it says in all the documentation I read, so I'll change it back - you're right, thanks.

Comment: Those two methods do the same thing.